# Angular translation not updating placeholder of Chosen plugin within ng-include $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-directive, angular-translate

I have an ng-view with multiple instances of the localytics (angular) Chosen plugin. I also have an ng-include with one instance of the plugin. Both rendered on the same page.

I'm using the **data-placeholder** attribute to render a value which is filtered through the angular-translate plugin.

Initially I was having issues with all Chosen instances rendering the translated text when the method to update the language was being called.
I got around this by calling $route.reload() at the end of the method (not ideal, but acceptable).

I tried:

- binding the values for the translations and the translate filter inline
- setting them in controllers
- watching the properties on the $scope (which never
  triggered)
- destroying the template before reloading the route

However, the placeholder within the ng-include refuses to update without the use of a hard refresh. Calling $window.location.reload() at the end of the method allows all instances to show the correct translation, but short of this I've not been able to find a way to fix the issue.

I'm assuming it's a scoping issue. Perhaps the Chosen plugin (which is a directive) creates its own scope, then the ng-include has its own scope, as does the ng-view.

All properties that are being translated, outside of the Chosen plugins, are working as expected.

Currently the angular-translate objects look like this:

`var translationEN = {
    SEARCH: {
        'SEARCH-BTN': 'Search'
    }
}`

So I'm binding them inline as per the following:

`<div ng-bind="'SEARCH.SEARCH-BTN' | translate">`

I've also attempted some of the methods on $translate, such as $translate.refresh() to no avail.

If anyone has any ideas, any help and / or comments are very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you put it into plunker? (http://plnkr.co/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `chosen` attribute to pass in some configurations instead of using the data-placeholder attribute, like this:

```
<select chosen="{'placeholder_text_single': 'Select the options'}"></select>
```

Or you can write custom attributes that the chosen directive will also accept as configurations. However, when using attributes, the directive will evaluate the expression instead of using the literal value, which won't work as expected for translation purposes, as '{{ ... }}' is not a valid expression. The attributes would be like this:

```
<select chosen placeholder-text-single="'Select the options'"></select>
```

Comment: `chosen="{'placeholder_text_single': ('TRANSLATE_KEY' | translate)}"` This works one time but doesn't change when translation changes. Do you have any solution for that, without having to change the chosen library?

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem occurred for me when the options were loaded by a promise.

With just an empty array, the translation worked fine, but putting the promise back in the code caused this behaviour.

A quick debugging in the `chosen` directive showed that, the `element`, from which the chosen angular plugin takes the template for the chosen widget, is not linked (or compiled... I'm really new with angular), it still contains the `{{placeholder.string | translate}}` value for the `data-placeholder` attribute, however, the `attr.placeholder` contains the tranlated value.

So this line sets wrong value as the default text: https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen/blob/master/chosen.js#L57

I extended the `chosen` directive with a `preLink` function, which modified the `element`'s `data-placeholder` attribute with the right value:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('chosen', function() {
return {
    priority : 1,
    restrict: 'A',
    link : {
        pre : function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            var defaultText = attr.placeholder;
            angular.element(element[0]).attr('data-placeholder', defaultText);
        }
    }
}
});
```